# Can we make a script for Google Doc that is automatically launched every weeks?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've a script that I've to launch every weeks, thats boring and if I'm not here, no one do it for me. So if we can do it, how did we do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **cron** to automatic scheduling of your tasks. More info you can find here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Cron is for unix system, but I found how to do what I want, its realy easy. When your on the Google Docs script editor page, you can execute a script from an event called Time-driven.

Answer (score 0):

When your on the Google Docs script editor page, you can execute a script from an event called Time-driven.

(*answer from the OP previously given as a comment*)